# View disk activity (IO/s, MB/s) of a Windows server remotely

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, performance-monitoring, remote-desktop-services, wmi

Our company does a lot of very network- and disk-intensive processing.  We would  benefit greatly from being able to glance at which of the five drives on the server are currently being "hit" or have a lot of read and write activity.  All the information that we would need to make decisions is very easily found in Windows 7/10's Resource Monitor.  We must be able to check the current drive activity, in the form of current MB/s, **from a remote location** on the internal network. [Here's an image of Resource Monitor.  Simple drive activity stats like the graphs on the right is all that we'd need.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjoYo.jpg)

I've tried to look into the following tools, with no success:

- The Windows Management Instrumentation PowerShell command, `Get-WmiObject`
- The Windows Management Instrumentation command-line command, `wmic`
- The System Information "Remote Computer..." option
- Dell PowerVault Modular Disk Storage Manager

None of these options seem to expose any of the drive activity of the storage controller.  Most of these get close, exposing data like capacity, serial numbers and labels, but no I/O or MB/s.

Our current solution is to have trusted department leads use Remote Desktop to remote into the storage controller and launch Resource Monitor or Dell PowerVault Modular Disk Storage Manager (either that, or call me).  This is problematic because only one RD connection can be active at one time and directly accessing the storage controller is a security/data integrity concern.

How do I configure our Windows Server 2012 R2 storage controller to publish or expose disk usage statistics to clients on the local network without using Remote Desktop?

Comment: maybe perfmon? .

Comment: You can connect to a remote computer with Perfmon. I'd suggest trying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Performance Monitor" to connect to another computer, gathering its performance data. As "Performance Monitor" can monitor many items, you obviously need to select the correct metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind this SysKit product.

You can check this application: https://www.syskit.com/features/server-performance-monitoring/

It can extract that data from the WMI remotely without any agent and then you can report in your infrastructure. Of course it this involves a lot of servers you might need to install the agent on your customer datacenter.